# Exclude whitespace that is only comprised of tab characters in RegEx Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to capture whitespace characters when there are two or more of them in a row, as well as individual, non-breaking spaces. My RegEx pattern is as follows and currently achieves this:

`/((\s|&nbsp;){2,}|&nbsp;)/g`

I would like to alter this pattern so that if two or more whitespace characters are only comprised of the tab `\t` character, then they are ignored. How would I do this?

Examples:

```
'\t\t' needs to be ignored
' \t' needs to be captured
'\t ' needs to be captured
' ' needs to be ignored
'\t' needs to be ignored
'&nbsp;\t' needs to be captured
' &nbsp;' needs to be captured
'&nbsp;' needs to be captured
```

Comment: Please edit your question under the assumption that you are trying to show us to full problem, not only the modification to the existing regex.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your recommendation. I've strived to write a clear problem statement; my existing Regex needs to be modified to exclude whitespace that is only comprised of tab characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
(( |\t|&nbsp;)*(?:&nbsp;)+[ \t]*| +[ \t]+|\t+ +[ \t]*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PrhlJH/5)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[ \t]*(?:&nbsp;)+[ \t]*`: Match 1+ `&nbsp;` surrounded by 0 or more space/tab characters
- `+[ \t]+`: Match 1+ space followed by 1+ space or tabs
- `\t+ +[ \t]*`: Match 1+ tabs followed by 1+ space and then 0 or more space/tabs

Comment: Hiya, this is very close. Thanks for your help. The only issue with your suggested pattern is that it does not capture a tab character when it precedes other whitespace: '\t '. Only when it follows...

Comment: Yes. My apologies. Basically, if there are multiple whitespace characters that are not comprised of pure tab characters, and are not individual non-breaking spaces, then they must be captured. I should have include `'\t '` in my OP. I will edit now.

Comment: `'\t\t '` would also be captured, as there is a space in there with the tab characters.

Comment: Single space ignored. Two or more spaces should be captured.

Comment: Heya, I tested your updated pattern and it didn't seem to work. But I was able to unpack what you'd done previously and then create this pattern, which does the trick: `((?:( |\t)*(?:&nbsp;)+( |\t)*)| +( |\t)+|\t+ +( |\t)*)`

Comment: Oddly, it didn't capture anything when I threw it into regexr. So I took your second-last answer and modified it. Perhaps you might refactor it further, if there is a more efficient way of capturing all the patterns. Here is my example here: https://regexr.com/52auh

Comment: Sounds good. Wanted to give you the points for all the effort ;)

Comment: ok I simplified a bit in latest youdate. This regex should be what you're looking for.